# update gui with SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I'm trying to update a `progressBar` with the value that a class generates and sends to a `SwingWorker`.

In the GUI I have this method:

```
@Override
public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
   if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("progress")) {
      int progress = (Integer) evt.getNewValue();
      jProgressBar1.setValue(progress);
   }
}
```

and I'm doing this also:

```
private void startWorker(){
     worker = WorkerUpdater.getInstance();    
     worker.addPropertyChangeListener(this);
     worker.execute();
}
```

In the `SwingWorker` I have a method `"setProgress"` to update the value of the variable from the object which calculates it and then I want that the `SwinWorker` reads this value ant repaint the `progressBar`.

How can I do that in the `doInBackground()` method? I have the next method but I want to update the `progressBar` every time the value of property "progress" change in the `SwingWorker`.

If I do that way it's working, but I want to update the progressBar only when other class modifies de value "progress" in the SwingWorker's atribute. How can I do it?

```
@Override
    public Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while(this.progress<100){
           setProgress(this.progress+10);
           this.progress += 10;
        }       
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> and then I want that the `SwinWorker` reads this value ant repaint the `progressBar`.

This isn't necessary - `SwingWorker` guarantees that the property change notification which will be delivered to the `PropertyChangeListener` whenever `setProgress` is called will take place on the event dispatch thread, so `propertyChanged` is the correct place to update components like the progress bar.

Comment: But I have to call setProgress in doInBackground() method? Can I call setProgress from the other class? Like this: Worker.getInstance().setProgress(x)

Comment: @mreigosa the issue is that `setProgress` is `protected` and `final` in SwingWorker so it's not accessible from outside your `Worker` class.  If you wanted to be able to call into it from outside then you'd have to write another method `public void progress(int p) { setProgress(p); }` or similar for "outsiders" to call.

Comment: I made that you said but the value of the progressBar didn't change. What's happening? I don't understand, because the value I send to the SwingWorker is correct. What has to do the SwingWorker in the background method?

Comment: @mreigosa and the GUI class that includes that `propertyChanged` method has definitely been registered as a PropertyChangeListener on the `Worker` instance?

Comment: @Ian Roberts there only a few flags from SwingWorker and PropertyChangeListener (START, END, PENDING, ERROR/EXCEPTION???)

Comment: I register the GUI as a PropertyChangeListener in the method startWorker.